# useing a input field in javascript to replace a div

Tags: javascript, html, var

I want then to fill in a date in the inputfield "datum" and that date have to replace the content of the div "test1". Can anyone help me out :P? I'm struggling on this for a while now haha. This is my code :

```
<form>
    Datum: <input type="text" id="datum">
</form> 

<script>

    var MyDiv1 = Document.getElementById('datum');

    document.getElementById("www").onclick = function() {   

        document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = 'MyDiv1';  
    };
</script>

<div id='test1'>This is a dummy text</div>
<a id="www" >Replace it!</a>
```

Comment: its `document` not `Document` at line `var MyDiv1 = Document.getElementById('datum');`

Comment: use document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML =  document.getElementById('datum').value;

Comment: Thanks everone for their answers! Helped me out alot! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lowercase 'document', remove the quotes around 'MyDiv1', and get the value, not the element itself.

```
 <form>
Datum: <input type="text" id="datum">
</form> 

<script>

  var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('datum');

document.getElementById("www").onclick = function() {


document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = MyDiv1.value;  
};
</script>

<div id='test1'>This is a dummy text</div>
<a id="www" >Replace it!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code:

- It's `document` not `Document` (as Arvind pointed out)
- You are trying to access the `www` element before it exists
- You are using the string `'MyDiv1'` instead of the variable `MyDiv1`
- You need to use the `value` property of the element instead of the element itself
- You need an `href` attribute on the link so that it's a link, not a bookmark
- You need to return `false` from the click handler, or the link will be activated

So:

```
<form>
Datum: <input type="text" id="datum">
</form> 

<div id='test1'>This is a dummy text</div>
<a href="#" id="www">Replace it!</a>

<script>

var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('datum');

document.getElementById("www").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = MyDiv1.value;
  return false;
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use below code this may be help you .

<form>
Datum: <input type="text" id="datum">
</form> 
<div id='test1'>This is a dummy text</div>

<a id="www" onclick="changetext();">Replace it!</a>

<script>

function changetext()
{
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById("datum").value;
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=MyDiv1;  
}

</script>
```